# Manipulation of an Image in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, image-manipulation, graphicsmagick

I want to change the **orientation** of an image as from portrait to landscape or vice-versa.

I tried doing it using many of the available npm packages :
* [rotate-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotate-image)
* [image-rotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-rotate)
* [jpegorientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpegorientation)
 
* [gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm)
* [rad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rad)

But each of these is one way or other not working as I want to do it or each has some or other limitations.
I tried to find a possible solution and search for it as much as I could. 
Most of the times,it has been done using ***gm***.
I tried doing the image manipulation using gm :

> Code:

```
var gm = require('gm');
gm('path/filename.jpg')
    .autoOrient()
   .write('path/destinationfile.jpg', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else
            console.log("Orientation changed successfully!");
    })
```

But I am getting an error as :

> Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "identify"
>   "-ping" "-verbose" "path/filename.jpg" this most likely means the
>   gm/convert binaries can't be found.

This error will be resolved only by using external binary libraries.I don't want to involve any kind of dependencies on 3rd party libraries.
 Can someone please help me out as of how to do it without pre-installing any of the external binary libraries (brew etc.) or how to use any of the existing package in a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [contain](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#contain) method from [lwip](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip) - Light Weight Image Processor for NodeJS

Here is an example:

```
// obtain an image object:
require('lwip').open('Example.jpg', function(err, image){
  // check err...
  // define a batch of manipulations and save to disk as JPEG:
  image.batch()
    .contain(image.height(), image.width(), 'black')
    .writeFile('output.jpg', function(err){
      // check err...
      console.log(err || 'Done');
    });
});
```

This swaps the orientation and fills the gaps in black.

I just tried it, and i only needed to install the lwip module into my application.

```
npm install lwip --save
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Robbie but do I need any CLI tools to install **lwip** ?
Because while installing lwip , its giving an error and asking for either **XCode** or **CLI tools**.

Comment: It sounds like you're using OSX, so you will need to to install xcode and the cli tools before you run `npm install lwip` locally - this is pretty standard, and probably worth doing anyway if you are developing on a mac. I forgot to mention it as i have it installed already - you can get xcode from here: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/ and then to install the CLI tools go to `Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads` - This will install gcc and the related toolchain containing make - and hopefully fix your error

Comment: Thanks a lot Robbie ..it worked finally, after struggling with that node-gyp error for the whole day.   @Robbie

Answer (score 1):

Mostly likely is the **PATH** problem (of CentOS). So I would try this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gm /usr/bin/gm
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/convert /usr/bin/convert
```

Hope it could help.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```